# Why new react preset installation in laravel gives error of The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying using React ui with laravel.
Command I run:

```
laravel new project
npm i
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui react
npm i & npm run dev
```

After this, when I do php artisan serve it says (About Example.js):

```
 ERROR: The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled
```

I have tried different solutions on google of creating **.babelrc** and **babel.config.js** files but nothing removes the error. Can anyone tells why is it so? What is proper configuration of react with laravel?

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed fresh laravel, it comes with **vite**.

Since you want to use React, just save the **.js** files in **resources/js** as **.jsx** and then run the npm run dev command again.

They explain it in the document: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#react

For blade files:

```
@viteReactRefresh
@vite('resources/js/app.jsx')
```

For source files: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#working-with-scripts

---

---

Or u can choose another path like this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia